# Mysql count per name reset per name change

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table with entries names,date etc.

```
select name from names
order by names
```

for example.

I need an output like

```
1|paul
2|paul
1|morne
1|marone
2|marone
3|marone
```

i have no clue where to start to do a count like this for when i grou i cant get this right.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, the easiest way to do this is with variables:

```
select n.name,
       (@rn := if(@name = name, @rn + 1, 1)) as seqnum,
       @name := name
from names n cross join
     (select @name := '', @rn := 0) var
order by names;
```

EDIT:

In case anyone comes across this answer, the above sort-of works, but MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  So, I now write the above as:

```
select n.name,
       (@rn := if(@name = name, @rn + 1,
                  if(@name := name, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as seqnum
from names n cross join
     (select @name := '', @rn := 0) var
order by names;
```

Because all the variable assignments are in one statement, there is no problem with the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` statement.